# Is $f(x)= \frac{1}{x} - \frac{1}{e^x-1}$ monotonic?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, derivatives, monotone-functions

We have $\displaystyle f(x)= \frac{1}{x} - \frac{1}{e^x-1}$, additionally $f(0)=\frac{1}{2}$. Determine whether $f(x)$ is monotonic.

I tried to do this by checking if $f'(x)<0$, however it does not look very helpful. I don't know if it's tricky, or I am just blind to something obvious here.

Thanks for any hints in advance!

Comment: think its monotonic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $f(x)$ be the function

$$f(x)=\frac{1}{x}-\frac{1}{e^x-1}$$

Then, we have

$$\begin{align}
f'(x)&=-\frac1{x^2}+\frac{e^x}{(e^x-1)^2}\\\\
&=\frac{-(e^x-1)^2+x^2e^x}{x^2(e^x-1)^2}\\\\
&=\left(\frac{e^x}{x^2(e^x-1)^2}\right)\left(x^2-4\sinh^2(x/2)\right)\\\\
&\ge 0
\end{align}$$

since the hyperbolic sine satisfies the inequality

$$|\sinh(x)|\ge |x|$$

Comment: The biggest issue I have with your answer is that I do not know sinh function (and any other function of this hyperbolic sort), so currently it is hard for me to fully understand it.

Comment: $\sinh(x)=\frac12 (e^x-e^{-x})$. To see that $|\sinh(x)|\ge |x|$, note first that $\sinh(0)=0$.  Then, simply show that $\frac{d}{dx}(\sinh(x)-x)\ge 0$.

Answer (score 2):

Observe that

$$f(x) = \frac{1}{x} - \frac{1}{2} \coth \frac{x}{2} + \frac{1}{2}.$$

Hence

$$f'(x) = -\frac{1}{x^2} + \frac{1}{4} \mathrm{cosech}^2 \frac{x}{2}.$$

So it is sufficient to prove that $4\sinh^2 \frac{x}{2} \ge x^2$ for $x \ge 0$. This follows from $\sinh y \ge y$ for $y \ge 0$.

Answer (score 0):

A function is monotone if its first derivative doesnt change sign. So here $1/x$ is continuously decreasing also $e^x$ is increasing so $\frac{1}{e^x-1}$ is decreasing function hence the function $f(x)$ is nonincreasing montonic function.

Comment: Why was this downvoted?

Comment: Whats the problem why a downvote

Comment: @ArchisWelankar I'm not sure why mine was downvoted as well

Comment: @ArchisWelankar It makes no sense. You have two decreasing functions, and you're subtracting them.Why does this imply that the difference is decreasing?

Comment: Yes i think  we both gave same answer ie first line of yours and mine but that cant be ateason for a downvote

Comment: The function can be written as $\frac{e^x-1-x}{x(e^x-1)}$ now can you see why the function is decreasing

Comment: @ArchisWelankar I agree. Your answer doesn't warrant a downvote; it was not me. Regardless, I don't really understand your logic (in particular, of your second sentence).